# Convert timestamp to day, month, year and hour

Tags: python, pandas

I have this following timestamp:

`TimeStamp="20160820T210239+0100"`

I would like to extract the year, month, day and hour from this format.

I'm working with pandas. Is there any way to parse this timestamp to the format I mentioned?

Kind regards

Comment: A regular expression with capture groups should do it easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use `to_datetime` function from `pandas`. In your case it should automatically pick up the date info, given the format:

```py
import pandas

df = pd.DataFrame([['20160820T210239+0100']], columns=['ts'])

df['date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['ts']) ## pandas recognizes your format

df['day'] = df['date'].dt.day
df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year

df
Out[1]:
    ts                      date                       day  month   year
0   20160820T210239+0100    2016-08-20 21:02:39+01:00   20  8       2016
```

I am assuming you need this in pandas, given the tag of the question. If you need just in pure `python`, you can use `datetime`:

```py
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('20160820T210239+0100', '%Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z')

print (dt.year, dt.month, dt.day)
Out[2]:
2016 8 20
```

Comment: Your second solution worked like a charm! Thanks :)